# Set php code on function.php for action hook post update

Tags: wordpress

I currently set below code on header.php.
Purpose is updating custom field.  It updates custom field when the post is **opened** by browser, and it works fine.

Now, I like to set this code on function.php, and run it when the post **updated**.

```
<?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>
<?php
$post_id = $post->ID;
if ( metadata_exists( 'post', $post->ID, '1aa'));
$modified = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '1aa', true );
update_post_meta($post->ID, '1aa', $modified);
?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Code on function.php seems to have unfamiliar lines for me.
Below code is something Im trying to write now.  It would be appreciated if somebody indicate if something wrong.

```
<?php
function update_custom_field( $post_id );
if ( is_single() ) :{
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    if ( metadata_exists( 'post', $post->ID, '1aa'));
    $modified = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '1aa', true );
    update_post_meta($post->ID, '1aa', $modified);

endif;}
add_action( 'post_updated', 'update_custom_field' );
?>
```

I sometimes see some mysterious number 10 or 3 like below usage.  Should I put this number too?

```
add_action( 'post_updated', 'update_custom_field', 10, 3 );
```

I made the code following nice advise.

```
function add_custom_field( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
if ( is_single() && metadata_exists( 'post', $post_id, '2a' ) ) :{
    $date = get_post_meta( $post_id, '2a', true );
    update_post_meta($post_id, '2a', $date );}
    else:{
    $date = get_the_date('Y-m-d', $post_id);    
    add_post_meta( $post_id, '2a', '$date', true );}
endif;
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'add_custom_field', 10, 3 );
```

However, this code does not effect on custom field '2a'.  When I ver_dump it, it shows date I wanted like 2020-03-11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in your PHP syntax, but mostly, your function isn't encapsulating anything and you are confusing `if` statement constructors (you only need `:` or `{` to open an `if`.

Here is what you are looking for:

```
function update_custom_field( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    if ( is_single() && metadata_exists( 'post', $post_id, '1aa' ) ) :
        $modified = get_post_meta( $post_id, '1aa', true );
        update_post_meta($post_id, '1aa', $modified);
    endif;
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_custom_field', 10, 3 );
```

Basically, we use the $post_id argument that is passed into the function. This argument is the `post id`.

Next, we combine both `if` statements, no reason to have two.

Then we do all the checking and modify your post meta.

The `add_action` is outside of the function. It can be before or after it, I tend to put the action after. I changed the hook to `save_post` since this will check on save and update.

To your question about the numbers:

1. The first number `10` is priority. That's when the action hook fires
   in relation to other functions on the **same** hook.
2. The second number `3` is arguments. The `save_post` hook (and `update_post`) hook takes three arguments: post_id, post and update: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/

Comment: Thank you !  Your explanation is easy to understand, and the code look beautiful !   Regarding this part ( $post_id, $post, $update ), Im wondering why are $post and $update are set here.  They do not appear in above code.

Comment: They are the arguments that are passed to the function. They do not need to be used. I only put them there as reference. You can easily leave them off, and then remove `10, 3` from the hook.

Comment: If I do not use those arguments like this,  function update_custom_field( $post_id), then I should change  10, 3 too?  or it does not related ( $post_id, $post, $update ) ?

Comment: It relates to that - so you can remove the `10, 3` if you wish. Honestly, I usually include all arguments even if I'm not using them just to keep track of what gets passed to the hook, but you can do just `$post_id` and remove the `10, 3`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I will follow your advise.  Will study about arguments.

Comment: It would be appreciated if you give me some more advise.  I updated my code following your advise.  Its shown above now.  However it does not affect anything on custom field.  ver_dump shows date information correctly.  I tried both update post meta and add post meta.

Comment: You are adding `{` and `}` which you do not need. Remove the `{` after the `if` statement, and remove the `}` after `add_post_meta( $post_id, '2a', '$date', true );}`

Comment: Thanks a lot !!  Now I see it works when it is new post.  Posts already made sometime before do not have meta field "2a" also.  Maybe I should change save_post part?  Sorry for many questions...

Comment: `save_post` works for new posts AND updates current posts. In order for your meta_field to appear, you need to save/update the old posts manually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209455/discussion-between-cwhiro-and-disinfor).